# how to find location of a substring and print it from there

Tags: c++, string

So far, I have this

```
if(tempString.find(mString) != string::npos) //if found word 
{
    cout<<endl<<tempString<<endl; //this prints the entire line
}
```

For example if the tempString was "For he I do not know" and the mString is "I do", it will print "I do not know"

I know that tempString.find(mString) returns the position of the substring. How do I use that to print starting at the substring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [std::string::substr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/):

```
size_t pos = tempString.find(mString);
if (pos != string::npos) 
{
  std::string to_print = tempString.substr(pos);
  cout << to_print;
}
```